# Finding a sequence of complex numbers ${z_n}$ such that $\sin z_n$ is real for all $n$ and tends to $\infty$ as $n→\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a sequence of complex numbers ${z_n}$ such that $\sin z_n$ is real for all
$n$ and tends to $\infty$ as $n→\infty$ ?

---

I get an example as $\log 2in$ . I want to verify that am I right or wrong. If I am right then can anyone give me some more examples.

Comment: Integral deleted his/her comment, but the solution was a good one: it is just that the sequence given worked for cosine, not sine.  But that is easily rectified, and the sequence $z_n=\frac{\pi}{2}+in$ works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

$z_n=\arcsin a_n$ where $a_n$ is any real-valued sequence which tends to $\infty$.

The inverse of the sine can be calculated via: $$\arcsin w=\frac{1}{i} \log \left( i w+\sqrt{1-w^2} \right)$$

(other branches are possible, of course)

Comment: So to give a specific example, $z_n=\pi/2 + \frac{1}{i}\log(n+\sqrt{n^2-1})$.

Comment: can anyone tell me please that my answer is right or not?

Comment: @user65544: No, your answer is not right.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this systematically: let $z = x + i y$, and you find
$$
\sin z = \frac{1}{2i}\left( e^{-y}(\cos x + i \sin x) - e^{-y}(\cos x - i\sin x) \right)
$$

Next you need the imaginary parts to cancel.  Then you'll find an expression for the real part in terms of some parameters, which you can choose appropriately to get a sequence tending to $\infty$.